# How long can a baby survive without water?

Tags: water, infant

If while there is a water shortage in the baby's country, when will mild dehydration, moderate and severe dehydration come. I wonder if a baby can survive longer than a parent in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[medscape.com](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/801012-overview)

> Infants' and children’s higher body water content, along with their
>   higher metabolic rates and increased body surface area to mass index,
>   contribute to their higher turnover of fluids and solute. Therefore,
>   infants and children require proportionally greater volumes of water
>   than adults to maintain their fluid equilibrium and are more
>   susceptible to volume depletion. Significant fluid losses may occur
>   rapidly, leading to depletion of the intravascular volume.

Babies cannot survive longer than their parents, due to one factor being that they utilize fluids faster. How long they survive depends on factor such as current fluid balance, body specific factors and diseases and environmental factors.